# Problema para mostrar imágenes con DOMPDF en un host

Tags: php, hosting, dompdf

mi problema es que estoy generando un archivo PDF en DOMPDF, la única imágen que tiene es del logo el cual se muestra perfectamente en el localhost pero al momento de subirlo a un host este me dice "imágen no encontrada".

Así es como lo mostraba en mi localhost:

```
        <td valign="top"><img src="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/estudio_arquitectura/assets/img/LogoJACTORRES.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" alt="" height="40"width="325"/></td>
```

Y así es como se ve cuando lo subí en un host:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría mostrarlo entonces?:((

Comment: en ciertos casos `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` viene vacío o defaultea al primer vhost, sugeriría reemplazarlo por un define o variable que calculas y validas previamente

Comment: Tendrías que poner la ruta completa de la imagen, integrando la url del hosting